# Missing Top/Bottom Panel in Gnome on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: gnome, panel

I am using Ubuntu 12.03 and the system recently installed some updates. Then I logged back in, the top and bottom panels (System, Time, etc) were missing from gnome. I thought it might be an issue with the graphics drivers so I updated my nvidia drivers to no effect using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

When I take a screenshot, the panels appear in a duplicated screen to the right that I cannot see on my screen. <kbd>Ctrl<kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+Left</kbd>/Right</kbd> do not change the workspace.

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot?

Comment: I tried to post a screenshot, however, it said that I need 10 rep points before I'm allowed to post images.

Comment: You can upload the image to some free image hosting services and include the URL as a link here

Comment: screenshot: [link](http://s10.postimg.org/p1o484r89/Screenshot_from_2013_04_13_14_21_47.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `gksu nvidia-settings`
2. You will get to see a window, similar to this

   [image: List item]
3. Select the window, by clicking, on which you want the Panel to appear
4. Then click on the `"Make this the primary display for the X screen"`
5. Click Apply

This should bring the Panel to the display of your preference.

From your question, I understand that your window manager also has changed.

To get back both the Top and Bottom panels,

1. Logout
2. After typing the username, click on the icon [image]
3. Then select Gnome Classic from that list
4. Now login, you should see both bottom and top toolbars

**NOTE:** In plain old Gnome (not Gnome classic), <kbd>Ctrl-Up</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl-Down</kbd>, will switch workspaces.